# Vectorise a code to transform a vector into a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, vectorization

I have a vector `A` of dimension `Nx1` in MATLAB, e.g.

```
N = 5;
A = [1
     2
     3
     4
     5];
```

I want to construct a matrix `B` of dimension `(N-1) x N` such that:
for `i=1,...,N`, `B(:,i)` contains the rows `1,2,...,i-1,i+1,...,N` of `A`.

---

In the example above,

```
B = [2 1 1 1 1
     3 3 2 2 2
     4 4 4 3 3
     5 5 5 5 4]
```

---

This code does what I want:

```
 B=zeros(N-1,N);
 for i=1:N
     if i>1 && i<N
         B(:,i)=[A(1:i-1); A(i+1:end)];
     elseif i==1
         B(:,i)=A(i+1:end);
     elseif i==N
         B(:,i)=A(1:i-1);
     end
 end
```

But I want to vectorise it. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what [`nchoosek`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html) generates with a clockwise [90 degree rotation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rot90.html).

```
B = rot90(nchoosek(A,N-1),-1);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple option:

```
[r, ~] = find(~eye(N));
B = reshape(A(r), N-1, N)
```

Answer (score 1):

per your example you can just delete every N+1 entry:

```
N=5;
a=repmat(1:N,1,N); % make an NxN long vector 
a(1:N+1:end)=[]; % delete every N+1 entry
B=reshape(a,N-1,[]) % reshape to N-1 x N matrix
```